# Reprensentation of integers in the form $\pm1^2\pm2^2\pm3^2\pm\ldots\pm k^2.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that every integer can be represented in the form $\pm1^2\pm2^2\pm3^2\pm\ldots\pm k^2$ for suitable choice of signs  and for some integer $k.$
I don't know how to prove this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$ \color{red}{+}n^2\color{red}{-}(n+1)^2\color{red}{-}(n+2)^2\color{red}{+}(n+3)^2 = \color{red}{4}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  prove that $n^2-(n+1)^2-(n+2)^2+(n+3)^2=4$
Show you can represent $1,2,3$
Why is this sufficient?